# Syntax error "undefined (". Where is the source of the error?

Tags: javascript, codepen

So I have what I believe is a syntax error. When I analyse the code in the codepen editor i get an error message of "undefined (". This appears on both line 186 & 200. I've never seen this error before.

This should be something I could find on my own but after doing several read-throughs of the code I can't seem to pick out where my mistake lies. I've run it through multiple js grammar checkers, but I got nothing significant.

here the link to the codepen:https://codepen.io/Leviathan_The_Great/pen/KqbpdY?editors=1111

and here is the source:

```
let activeGreeting; 
function displayGreeting(classSelector){

  let greetingHeaders = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName("greeting-text") ); 
  greetingHeaders = greetingHeaders.map((ElNode)=>{
      if( /-?(\.|[_a-zA-Z])+(\.|[_a-zA-Z0-9-])*/.test(ElNode) ){
        throw new Error("string passes does not appear to a valid CSS class")  
      }

      if( /^\./m.test(ElNode) ){
          return ElNode
      }else{
          return '.' + ElNode  
      }
  }) 

  let textToShow = document.querySelector(`.greeting-text${classSelector}`);  
  textToShow.style.display = "block"
}
//scene finding and 
var activeScene;
//list of available scenes
const scenes = [document.getElementById('Scene-Day'), document.getElementById('Scene-Night'), document.getElementById("Scene-Valentine's") ];


//main function to calculate the day and which scene to use
(function(){
  // for logic testing:
  //var date = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:00:00') 
  //var date = new Date('December 17, 1995 06:25:00')
  //var date = new Date('December 17, 1995 12:42:00')
  //var date = new Date('December 17, 1995 17:42:00')
  //Valentines day 2019
  //var date = new Date('1550161356000')

  const date = new Date();
  const time = date.getHours().toString() + date.getMinutes().toString();

  if(date.getDate() === 17 && date.getMonth() === 3){
    activeScene=scenes[4];
    console.log('its st.patricks day');
  }   
  if(date.getDate() === 31 && date.getMonth() === 10){
    activeScene=scenes[5];
    console.log("its Halloween day");
  }  
  if(date.getDate() === 14 && date.getMonth() === 2){
    activeScene = scenes[3];
    console.log("its valentines day");
    let greetingText = document.querySelector(".greeting-text.valentine's")
    greetingText.style.display = "block";
  }else{
    console.log("it is not a special day");
    //*commented out for scene testing
    if (600 <= time && time <= 1200){
      activeScene = scenes[0];
      let greetingText = document.querySelector(".greeting-text.morning")
      greetingText.style.display = "block";
      console.log("it is daytime");
    }
    else if(1200 < time && time <= 1700){
      activeScene = scenes[0];

      let greetingText = document.querySelector(".greeting-text.afternoon")
      greetingText.style.display = "block";

      console.log("it is the afternoon")
    }
    else if(1700 < time && time <= 1700){
      activeScene = scenes[1];

      let greetingText = document.querySelector(".greeting-text.evening")
      greetingText.style.display = "block";

      console.log("it is evening");
    }
    else if(1700 < time && time <= 2400 || time < 600 ){
      activeScene = scenes[1];

      let greetingText = document.querySelector(".greeting-text.night")
      greetingText.style.display = "block";

      console.log("it is night");
    }
  } 
})();


(function passiveCloudAnimation(){

 function assignSpeedToUndeclaredClouds(clouds, cloudSpeeds){
      cloudSpeeds.shift()
      let startingArrayLength = cloudSpeeds.length;
      for(let i = 0; i < clouds.length - startingArrayLength; i++ ){

        let ROV = cloudSpeeds,
            range = Math.max(...ROV) - Math.min(...ROV),
            randomValInRange = Math.min(...ROV) + ( Math.random() * range );

        cloudSpeeds[startingArrayLength] = randomValInRange    
      }
      cloudSpeeds.unshift(null)

      return cloudSpeeds 
}

  /*start of main script*/

  let clouds = [],
      cloudTLs = [],

      cloudSpeeds = [
          null,
          9,
          9.5,
          8
      ];
  if( clouds.length > cloudSpeeds.length ){
      let cloudSpeedsExtended = f();
      cloudSpeeds = assignSpeedToUndeclaredClouds()
  }

  //retrieve and store clouds

  let s_ = document.getElementsByClassName("cloud-container");
  s_ = Array.from(s_)
  clouds.push(...s_)



  for(let i = 1; i < clouds.length; i++){
    let tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});
    tl.to( `#cloud-${i}`, 9, {transform:"translateX(94vw)", ease:power0.easeNone} )
    tl.to( `#cloud-${i}`, 9, {transform:"translateX(0vw)", ease:power0.easeNone} )  
    cloudTLs.push(tl)
  }

  clouds.map(()=>{
        // code for attaching the event listeners  
  });

})();





//sets up animation scene
(function setup(){
  activeScene.style.display = "initial";
  //this is likly why tweenmax is taking a 360 rotation in the next code section
  TweenMax.set(document.getElementsByClassName('Scene-Svg'),{rotation:180});
  console.log('scene is setup');
})();

(function comeIn(){
  //apparently tweenmax is not defined here
  TweenMax.to(activeScene, 3, {delay:0.9,rotation:"360_CW",ease:Bounce.easeOut});
  console.log('animation entered');
})();

function leave(){
      TweenMax.to( activeScene, 1.5, { rotation:'180_CW', ease:Power1.easeOut } );
      //TweenMax.to(activeScene,0.4, {delay:3,rotation:360});
      console.log('animation has left');
};

function startPassiveAnimation(){
    function satelliteAnimation(satelliteClass){
      var satelliteContainer = document.querySelector('');
      var satellite = document.querySelector(''); 
      return passiveTL.add(TweenMax.set(satelliteContainer,{transformOrigin:'100% 50%', rotation:0})) 
                      .add(TweenMax.to(satelliteContainer,4,{rotation:0}))
                      .add(TweenMax.to(satellite,3,{rotation:360, repeat:-1}));

    }

    let satTimeline = satelliteAnimation();

};
```

Comment: all i am seeing is "power0 is not defined"

Comment: I get one error - *Uncaught ReferenceError: power0 is not defined* in both Chrome & FF.  If I comment out those 2 lines I get no syntax errors.

Comment: the only thing I see is "ReferenceError: power0 is not defined"  your Error probably is coming from some **other js file** that you included?

Comment: th only other scripts I included are libraries, these to be exact: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js

Comment: update: I removed the lines of code containing, as was suggested. but the identical errors still persist. I feel like this might be a problem with codepen as nobody has seen anything else. has anybody else seen this error?